# Where is the root file(main.dart) in a flutter project located?

Tags: flutter, dart

I just bought a flutter UI from online. Now I couldn't find the root file where all the package and classes imported.

**Is there any solution to find the root class?**

Comment: normally all the code files are under a lib folder. Please share a link to a repository or any materials that can help the community help you further

Comment: Please add more details to your post, it will help others providing a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have purchased a commercial Flutter Widget, then usually the documentation will ask you to add an entry to the **pubspec.yaml** file. After that flutter will download the dependencies and will merge them with your project.

All you have to do is to reference the package in your source code through a simple import function.

Take a look at an example here:
https://pub.dev/packages/mobx/install

You add a pubspec entry, save, your IDE will download the dependencies, then import the package into your source code.